# Online discussion section or online discussion session?

Tags: word-choice

In an online course, there are sessions every, e.g., two weeks in which the teacher and the students hold an online Q&A meeting. It seems that both "online discussion section" and "online discussion session" are used to refer to such a session, but I myself think that session is more correct and section may be a common mistake. Am I right?

Comment: A _section_ is a part of something. It would only be appropriate to call the discussion a section if it formed only a part of the lesson.

Comment: "online discussion section" could refer to a part of the website where "online discussion sessions" are discussed, reviewed or where material for them is stored.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Website? The domain of the question is an online class.